# What is the difference between a 10a and 15a powerpoint?

Tags: electrical

I accidentally pulled a powerpoint out of the wall when I unplugged an appliance.

Looking at Bunnings there seems to be 2 choices. 10amp or 15amp.

https://www.bunnings.com.au/deta-double-power-point_p4430414
https://www.bunnings.com.au/deta-15a-double-power-point_p4430422

What is the difference? Can I get either? When would I use one over the other?

This is Australia by the way.

Comment: "Powerpoint" is a somewhat unfamiliar term for most of us. To save others a moment's confusion, it's a duplex receptacle (just for Australian plugs).

Comment: It definitely matters. Why can't you reinstall the old one? Can you post a picture (or upload it and post a link)? Can you find out what the old device was rated? The wires servicing the receptacle are only rated for a certain current (or lower), so you could be putting yourself at risk by installing a receptacle rated for higher current.

Answer (score 1):

Earthing pin is taller.  This is a way of keying the receptacle so a 10A or 15A load can plug into a 15A receptacle, but a 15A load (tall earth) cannot plug into a 10A receptacle.

North America does exactly the same with NEMA 5-15 and 5-20 and 6-15 and 6-20, just more obviously (which helps users understand why it won't fit).

[image]

And it's probably the same thing: it means the cabling behind the receptacle is either the thinner cable that saves money, or the thicker cable with higher current rating installed at extra cost. With a different size overcurrent device (breaker) for each to protect the wires.

Comment: Note that in Aus, the cabling is likely rated for 16 or 20A even if the sockets are all 10A.